# Implement $\max$ with a closed form expression?

Tags: nonlinear-optimization

I have 2 functions: $f(x)$ and $g(x)$. Both of them range in $[0,1]$.

Is there some way to define a $h(x)$ that efficiently takes the greater one of $h(x)$ and $g(x)$, i.e. $h(x) = \max \{ f(x),g(x) \}$, but without using $\max$?

If there is no exact solution, an approximate $h(x)$ is also fine.

Comment: What's wrong with max?

Comment: The Heaviside step function is accepted?

Answer (score 6):

Since you ask for alternatives, note that
$$\max\{s,t\}=\tfrac12s+\tfrac12t+\tfrac12|s-t|,
$$
and that, if one also wants to avoid absolute values,
$$\max\{s,t\}=\tfrac12s+\tfrac12t+\tfrac12\sqrt{t^2+s^2-2st}.
$$
Both these formulas are actually *less* handy than the maximum you started from (the square-root formula being probably even less handy than the absolute-value one)...

Comment: Nice point! I agree that the $max$ is probably more handy. @Jokester And by the way, what do you mean for *efficient*? What do you want to do?

Comment: Here is one possible application of the former formula: after proving that the Riemann integrable functions form a vector space over the reals, and proving that absolute value preserves Riemann integrability, it becomes easy to show that max preserves Riemann integrability.